# Symfony2: disable vendor event listeners

Tags: symfony, service, listener, single-sign-on, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony2 application I'm working on that uses SSO and the FosUserBundle. However there is a FosUserBundle event listener which is triggered when a user logs in and therefore stops my SSO bundle from working.

Is there a way in my `app/config/config.yml` that I can easily disable this specific FosUserBundle listener?

PS. The listener is `FOS\UserBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener::onSecurityInteractiveLogin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that it is the responsibility of the bundle to provide configuration for disabling some of its behaviour.

So, if it's not the case, make the changes (enabling by default the event listener) and send a PR :)

Here's some example of enabling/disabling through configuration: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/blob/develop/DependencyInjection/KnpRadExtension.php#L27-L57

With the according configuration:  https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/blob/develop/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L32-L38

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the service definition and use a stub class that has the same interface, but does nothing.

```
services:
    acme.menu.adaptor:
        class: MyProject\Helper\NullMenuAdapter
        tags:
            -  { name: 'acme.menu.adaptor' }
```

Sometimes you can remove tags if the service relies on them:

```
services:
    acme.menu.adaptor:
        class: Acme\Helper\RealMenuAdapter
#        tags:
#            -  { name: 'acme.menu.adaptor' }
```

Comment: @julestruong yep!

Answer (score 2):

Glancing through the EventDispatcher code, I can't see any easy way to disable one specific listener in config.yml.

One thing you could do would be to extend LastLoginListener with your own class, set the parameter `fos_user.security.interactive_login_listener.class` (see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/security.xml) to your extended class, and override `getSubscribedEvents()` with something like the following:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onImplicitLogin',
    );
}
```

Thus removing the subscription for the `SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN` event.

Not sure if this is the cleanest way to do this, but it's probably the one that requires the least lines of code.

EDIT:

To further elaborate on my answer, the reason why I think it's not possible to disable a specific listener method through the config files is because the LastLoginListener uses the kernel.event_subscriber tag to indicate it's listening for custom events.

The `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\RegisterKernelListenersPass` class calls the `getSubscribedEvents()` method on each of the services with the kernel.event_subscriber tag and then adds an event subscription for all of the returned classes + callbacks.

Nowhere in the code that sets this up does there appear to be any overrides.

I'm basing all this on looking through the code, however, so there may be an option somewhere that I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in Symfony 5, I needed to override some vendor service. For this purpose `alias` worked for me. So in services.yaml you can define:

```
  Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener:
    alias: App\Service\NewRelic\ExceptionListener
```

`Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\ExceptionListener` is the service ID which I want to override. You can find service ID by running:

```
php bin/console debug:container
```